# After removing html tags from string second line start with new line in ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic4, newline

I want to remove HTML tags from the response.

I have done it but now the issue is second line start with the new line but it continues with the first line.

**.ts**

```
this.slokData = data.slok;
this.slok = this.transform(this.slokData);

transform(value: string) {
    if (value) {
      var result = value.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, ""); //removing html tag using regex pattern
      console.log("Transform : " + result);
      return result;
    }
    else { }
}
```

It removes all the tags but each line starts with the other.

How to start with the new line?

Comment: Can you post the `value` example?

Comment: It is solved. Besides removing tag I applied it in Html.